# suppress an unused variable warning

Tags: kotlin

How can I suppress the inspection in Kotlin for an unused variable

`val xyz = abc`

I get the squiggly line but `ALT-ENTER` is useless for this, I tried also to create in another method several variables unused and they also lack the `ALT-ENTER` ability to ignore the warning. Although I have definitely used `ALT-ENTER` for this in the past, although maybe it was only in java, can't remember.

So I must manually construct it by hand. I've been trying several variations but I can't get anything to work. Please tell me the correct `//noinspection` or `@SupressWarnings` to use, thanks

Comment: Alt-Enter, expand the first suggested option (labeled "Remove variable 'xyz'"), choose one of the options suggested, labeled "Suppress 'UNUSED_VARIABLE' for xxx". That said, I really don't understand the point of keeping such an unused variable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA, a right-side arrow on an ALT+ENTER context menu (like this: [image]) means that you can use your arrow keys to navigate further along the menu. In this case, it leads to your answer:

[image]

```
@Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE")
val unused = ""
```

If you do not get the initial context menu (`Remove variable '...'`), you may have disabled the "Unused assignment" inspection in your current project. You can fix this by going to Settings -> Editor -> Inspections.

Comment: thanks, it works now. What was confusing me was that there was no remove option - only a safe delete - so I ignored that before because I usually don't like safe delete. But I found similar options under the safe delete for supression